# c++ define directive on class in header file

Tags: c++

I am somewhat aware of what the #define directive does and its conveniences but what does it mean when using it on a class such as:

```
#ifndef SAVINGS_H
#define SAVINGS_H
#include "account.h"

class Savings
{
protected:
public:
};
#endif
```

If SAVINGS_H is not defined, it defines SAVINGS_H, but where is SAVINGS_H ever used? And why is the class referred to as SAVINGS_H in all capital letters?

I know when you define a variable such as

```
#define num 1

int arr[num]
```

num gets replaced with 1 but for my question, SAVINGS_H is not used any where else in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is called [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). It's so that you header is included only once (to avoid ODR violations, i.e. multiple definitions of the same entity).

For example if `A` includes `B` and `C` but `B` also includes `C`.

Basically they work this way: when compiler includes the header the 1st time it defines the include guard macro. In all the subsequent includes it just skips the file contents, since the macro is already defined (ifndef).

Answer (score 2):

If your source code (by whatever path) did this:

```
  #include "savings.h"
  #include "savings.h"
```

then `SAVINGS_H` *would* be defined after the first `#include`, and would prevent a re-definition of the names in the `savings.h` header file. This is what is known as an "include guard", and prevents redefinition of names in header files in the same translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "header guard" aka "include guard".

The purpose is to prevent multiple inclusion (including multiple transitive inclusion) of the header file. Which would lead to problems with the same type being defined multiple times.